# :host (body) not working in Angular

Tags: css, angular

I'm trying to figure out how to write CSS in the home.component.css but it isn't working.

I tried

```
:host-context(body) 
  { 
    background-color: #eee; 
  }
```

and also

```
:host() body 
  { 
    background-color: #eee;
  }
```

but isn't working.

What am I possible doing wrong?

Comment: what are you trying to add `background` color to?

Comment: Just try `:host { background-color: #eee; }`

Comment: @AngularInDepth.com in the home.component.html

Comment: @Faisal It's not working. How would that work? Because the CSS must go to `<body>` tag.

Comment: If you're using Angular-CLI (recommended), you can just use the `styles.css` file in your `src` folder. Just do `body { background-color: #eee }`.

Comment: You are trying to style the component selector, that should work. Otherwise use a class to wrap your component template

Comment: P.S. there is nothing like angularjs 2, #ItsJustAngular

Comment: If I do that, then every page would have background-color: #eee @Z.Bagley

Comment: It's confusing us because @AngularInDepth.com has the answer for styling the host component, but you're requesting body at the same time... these are two different things.

Comment: I'm thinking they want to dynamically change the body background color when different components are loaded... not sure at this point.

Comment: @Z.Bagley, I've updated my answer to reflect that

Answer (score 6):

You can's style elements outside of component view neither with `:host` nor with `:host-context`. You need to use `ViewEncapsulation.None` for that.

If you want the `body` to have some background only when the route for `home` component is loaded, here is what you can do. You can create a wrapper component that will style the body using `ViewEncapsulation.None` which will house the `home.component` inside so that styles of HomeComponent are still encapsulated  inside the `HomeComponent`.

```
@Component({
   encapsulation: ViewEncapsulation.None,
   template: `<home-component>...`,
   styles: [`body { background-color: #eee; }...`]
})
export class WrapperComponent {}

routes = [
   {
       path: 'home',
       component: WrapperComponent
```

Comment: This doesn't work either. I'm trying to apply the CSS to the `<body>` tag of this specific page only.

Answer (score 2):

this work for me:

```
:host-context(body)
{
  background-color: darkred;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  display: block;
}
```

must do a block display.
It's work only for one component

Answer (score 1):

Using `ViewEncapsulation.None` can cause massive `css` conflict especially if the two component has same `class`es and are nested within each other. (trust me I've been there.) Try this solution it worked for me.

```css
// NO spaces between `>>>`. I.E. IntelliJ auto format with spaces
:host() >>> body 
  { 
    background-color: #eee;
  }
```

You need to `>>>` to force the component to use `css` provided by the parent component instead of its own `css` file's styling.